# Singular Word Substring Method

Tags: java

I'm having trouble determining why my substring when it is returned is always "". When single words are passed (Ex. Chemistry) I get something like the following:

```
 C
 h
 e
 m
 i
 s
 t
 r
 y
```

A blank line is then printed as the substring value of "".

```
public String NextString(String lstring){
    String substring="";
    int i=0;
    while (lstring.charAt(i)!=' ') {
        System.out.println(lstring.charAt(i));
        substring.concat(Character.toString(lstring.charAt(i)));
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(substring);
    return substring;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: What's wrong? It seems worked as your code.

Comment: `substring = substring.concat(Character.toString(lstring.charAt(i)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reassign the concatenated string.  Try this instead:

```
substring = substring.concat(Character.toString(lstring.charAt(i)));
```

Reference: [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

the string in java is immutable and when you assign it you can't change the value in it again 
for that like "Devendra Lattu" said you need to assign the output of  concatenation every time you concatenate new character to variable

```
substring=substring.concat(Character.toString(lstring.charAt(i)));
```

if you don't like this you can use StringJoiner from java 8 [link to it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) its faster and mutable 
I'm sorry for first answer :)

Comment: Don't recommend StringJoiner. That is more of an internal thing. Go for StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why your substring is not getting printed, because when you are doing concatenation you are not storing it in **substring** as a result at the end of loop **substring** is still blank.
Try below changes :

```
String substring="";
int i=0;
while (lstring.charAt(i)!=' ') {
    System.out.println(lstring.charAt(i));
    substring=substring.concat(Character.toString(lstring.charAt(i)));
    i++;
}
System.out.println(substring);
return substring;
```

Comment: No explanations... No upvotes. That is what happens to most answer that come code only.

Answer (score 0):

String objects are immutable. Thus concat() does not change substring, but returns a changed string. Thus you need

```
substring = substring.concat(...
```

Beyond that: you want to iterate the chars of that string. You absolutely do not need that complicated while loop for that. Instead use the for-each loop style here:

```
for (char singleChar : lstring.getCharArray()) {
```